# Delaying "for each" method

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying delete the channels of server for server admins. It's for when the Server Owner wants to reset discord, he could use the command. However it was to fast so I needed add a delay before deleting each channel cause Discord employees can think its raid. Here's my code;

```
if (message.member.id == "<Server Owner ID>") {
    message.guild.channels.forEach(channel => {
        setTimeout(function(){channel.delete()}, 3000);
    });
}

else {
    message.channel.send("You don't have permission to execute this command.").then(msg => {
        msg.delete("5000")
    })
}}
```

How can I handle with this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use another parameter in the `forEach` callback to indicate the index of the current item being iterated over, and set the timeout to some multiplier of that index. That way, for example, the first timeout will trigger after 3 seconds, the second will trigger after 6 seconds, etc.

```
message.guild.channels.forEach((channel, i) => {
  setTimeout(() => channel.delete(), (i + 1) * 3000);
});
```

Comment: Good and simple solution. another way would be chaining a bunch of promises but I feel like that would overcomplicate the situation a bit.

Comment: Now I'm facing this problem
{(node:3700) TimeoutOverflowWarning: 1.4712356064527647e+22 does not fit into a 32-bit signed integer.
Timeout duration was set to 1.}

Could it be because of discord.js?

Comment: @HzMeth That's a peculiar error. I was assuming that `.channels` was an array and that the number of channels is reasonable (less than a million, for example). Might you `console.log((i + 1) * 3000);` inside the `forEach`? It *shouldn't* be very high, I would think...

Comment: @CertainPerformance 
`1.4712521338689946e+22
1.4712531854728888e+22
1.471253210513277e+22
1.4712532352890307e+22
1.4712532605425418e+22` It's like that but I guess this problem cause of discord.js. Thanks for everything btw ^^

Comment: @HzMeth I think I see the problem, the `channels` is a [Collection](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection), which extends `Map`, and is not an array. The `i` argument is the *internal key* (which is apparently a very high integer), not the iteration index. Try converting the Map to an array first: can you try `[...message.guild.channels].forEach(...` and see if it works?